# Error while creating an account on Windows from a Linux server using LDAP (Issues with TLS/SSL connection)

Tags: ssl, active-directory, ldap, tls1.2, openldap

I am trying to create an account on Windows AD from a Linux(RHEL) server using the `ldapadd` command.

When I ran the `ldapadd` command without a TLS/SSL connection, I encountered the following error:

```
ldapadd -d 255 -v -H ldap://[Window IP] -D "admin@[Domain Name] -w [Password] -f ldap_user.ldif
```

Error: ldapadd server is unwilling to perform (53)
Additional info: 0000209A: SvcErr: DSID-031A1030, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

I couldn't find any information about the 209A error code anywhere.

- There are no issues with password policies or account creation permissions.

The command:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://[Window IP] -b [~] -D "admin@[Domain Name] -w [Password]
```

works perfectly fine.

So, I thought that an ldapSSL/TLS connection might be necessary.

I generated a certificate for the computer account from the Windows server's MMC and received it in base64 format (filename: ca.cer).

When I executed the command:

```
ldapadd -d 255 -v -H ldaps://[Window IP]:636 -D "admin@[Domain Name] -w [Password] -f ldap_user.ldif
```

(Note: I changed it to ldaps://~:636), I got the same error:
ldapadd server is unwilling to perform (53)
Additional info: 0000209A: SvcErr: DSID-031A1030, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

The debug log showed:
tls_read: want=5 error=Bad file descriptor

When I ran:

```
openssl s_client --connect [Window IP]:636 -CAfile ca.cer
```

I received: "Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)".

I checked if it is an IP and port with SSL/TLS access.

I also registered the certificate on the Linux server.

What else can I try?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AD requires that the connection be encrypted to set the password. So yes, you need to get LDAPS working.

For TLS to work (in general, not just for ldapadd) your computer needs to trust the certificate - either trust the issuer, or specifically trust that one cert, which is sounds like you did. But also, the domain name on the cert has to match the domain name you're using to connect. In this case, you're using an IP address to connect, which will never match. You need to change `ldaps://[Window IP]:636` to use the domain name in the cert. For example, `ldaps://example.com:636`. If DNS isn't setup for the domain name you used, then add the IP and domain to /etc/hosts

Comment: Thank you for your response! It was very helpful.

To trust the certificate, I received a certificate chain in a pem file and changed the domain to successfully receive a return of 0(ok).

```
openssl s_client --connect [Window Domain]:636 -CAfile ca.pem
```

(I converted the pfx file issued from the Windows server to pem.)

Comment: However, I'm still getting the error "ldapadd server is unwilling to perform (53) Additional info: 0000209A: SvcErr: DSID-031A1030, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0". The debug log also shows the same "tls_read: want=5 error=Bad file descriptor".

I feel like I've tried most of the solutions available online. Do you have any additional suggestions on what I could try?

Comment: The issue has been resolved by removing the read-only attribute in the LDIF file, setting the encodePwd, and granting groups with the userAccountControl permission. Thank you for your response!